# How do I change a column of a data frame from float to integer(Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I am attempting to edit an entire column cell by cell to change the column from something that contains integer and string to just the integer component.

Actual column from data frame:

```
0                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
1                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
2                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
3                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx     
8                  667788; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
9                  55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
10                 55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
11                 55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
12                 33333; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
13                 333; xxx xxxxx @ xxx xxx 2 xxxx   
14                 9991; xxxx; xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx @ 2 xxx   
18                       1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10   
19                       1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10   
20                       1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10   
21                       1635; vvvvvvvvvvvv vvvvvv 10     
32                       1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0   
33                       1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0   
34                       1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0   
35                       1712; Cxxxx xxxxxxxx; xxx 0
```

This is the code I am running

```
 import pandas as pd 
    import re

    # import excel file from Trello
    xlsx = pd.ExcelFile("/home/deon/Documents/Work_Stuff/Trello.xls") 
    # create data frame from excel file on sheet 1
    df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx,'Sheet1')
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)

    # delete columns not relative to us
    df3.drop(df3.columns[[0,5,10,11]],inplace=True,axis=1)
    df3.columns= "Date*", "Due date", "Week*", "Card", "Board", "List", "S", "E 1st"

    df3[:, 6] = df3.iloc[:,6].apply(lambda x: x.split(';')[0]) 
    print df2.head()


# Also tried
    digits = df3.iloc[:, 4].apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+', str(x)))
    df3.iloc[:, 4] = digits.str.get(0).astype(int)
    print df3.head()
```

Comment: It seems to me the first code block will give you what you want, but in string form. You just have to convert that to int. What output are you getting from that?

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: for the second example I received: ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer

Comment: Interesting. Can you give just a little more info on how this dataframe is built? What is the variable type in one entry of your column? Can you call type() on it and post here?

Comment: 'code'(0                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
1                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
2                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   
3                           11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx     
8                  667788; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
9                  55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   
10                 55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx   )  <type str>

Answer (score 0):

You had the general idea for splitting the string, your trouble came when referencing into the dataframe.  Something more along the lines of:

**Code:**

```
df['number'] = df.raw_string.apply(lambda x: int(x.split(';')[0]))
```

**Test Code:**

```
data = [x.strip() for x in """
             11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
             11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
             11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
             11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
    667788; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
    55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
    55555; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['raw_string'])

df['number'] = df.raw_string.apply(lambda x: int(x.split(';')[0]))

print(df.head())
```

**Results:**

```
                             raw_string  number
0            11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   11212
1            11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   11212
2            11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   11212
3            11212; xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx   11212
4  667788; xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx  667788
```